# Glassfish - Slow requests from Windows clients

Tags: glassfish

we have a weird problem with our Glassfish 3.1 installed over a Centosx64. If we access our web app from a pc running ubuntu (firefox or chrome browser) it all works ok, but if we do the same from a pc running windows, every request (css, post/j_security, jsf.js) is extremely slow.

Do you guys know what could be the possible cause of this problem or at least point us to the right direction?

Thanks so much in advance,
Regards.

Comment: does this also happen with chrome on windows? or is it just Internet Explorer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Ludjer. But it was an update on debian(x86_64) kernel and on some libraries named libnss. Something affecting the firewall i guess, updating again solved the problem!